# javascript popup window with switch statement

Tags: javascript, html

Create a button called “GO TO OTHER WEBSITES” on your form that will call a function to give a popup window to go to the user’s choice of url and window size. 
The function will use a prompt box to give the user at least 3 choices of urls (other websites related to your website) to choose from.

Use a switch statement to set the chosen url and validate the user choice, do not continue until you have a valid choice. 
The user will then be prompted to enter the height and width of the window in pixels. This must be validated for a minimum height and width of 500. Do not continue until you have a valid height and width.
Display the chosen url in a window using this resolution. (Hint: to set the additional properties of the window.open method you will need to create a string variable to set the width and height.)

---

Here is my HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src= "../javascript/a1.js"></script>
    <title>HTML5 Template</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <h1>Sign Up form</h1>
    <form name="userForm" onsubmit= "return validateForm()" >

    First name: <input type="text" id="firstname" size="30" />
    <br><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" id="lastname" size="30" />
    <br><br>
    Postcode: <input type="text" id="postcode" size="30" />
    <br><br>
    Email: <input type="text" id="email" size="30" />
    <br><br>
    <h1>Payment details</h1>
    <br>
    Credit Card:<select name="Credit Card">
    <option value="Visa">Visa</option>
    <option value="Mastercard">Mastercard</option>
    <option value="American Express">American Express</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    Card Number: <input type="text" id="cardnumber" size="30" />
    <br><br>
    CCV: <input type="text" id="ccv" size="30" />
    <br><br>
    Expiry MM/YY:<SELECT id="exMonth" title="select a month" >
    <OPTION VALUE="0" SELECTED>--Month--
    <OPTION VALUE="01">01
    <OPTION VALUE="02">02
    <OPTION VALUE="03">03
    <OPTION VALUE="04">04
    <OPTION VALUE="05">05
    <OPTION VALUE="06">06
    <OPTION VALUE="07">07
    <OPTION VALUE="08">08
    <OPTION VALUE="09">09
    <OPTION VALUE="10">10
    <OPTION VALUE="11">11
    <OPTION VALUE="12">12
    </SELECT> /
    <SELECT id="exYear" title="select a year">
    <OPTION VALUE="0" SELECTED>--Year--
    <OPTION VALUE="2016">2016
    <OPTION VALUE="2017">2017
    <OPTION VALUE="2018">2018
    <OPTION VALUE="2019">2019
    <OPTION VALUE="2020">2020
    <OPTION VALUE="2021">2021
    <OPTION VALUE="2022">2022
    <OPTION VALUE="2023">2023
    <OPTION VALUE="2024">2024
    <OPTION VALUE="2025">2025
    <OPTION VALUE="2026">2026
    <OPTION VALUE="2027">2027
    </SELECT>




    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
    <input type="button" onClick="Help()" value="Help">

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

---

Here is my java script code

```
function validateForm()
{
var firstname=document.getElementById("firstname");
var lastname=document.getElementById("lastname");
var postcode=document.getElementById("postcode");
var email=document.getElementById("email");
var cardnumber=document.getElementById("cardnumber");
var ccv=document.getElementById("ccv");


//var message= ""
// message += \n   makes all the message display in one box  //

    if (firstname.value=="")
    {
        alert("Please enter your first name");
        firstname.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (lastname.value==""){
        alert("Please enter your last name");
        lastname.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (postcode.value.length!=4 || isNaN(postcode.value)){
        alert("Please enter 4 numbers for your postcode");
        postcode.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (email.value.indexOf("@")== -1 ) {
        alert("Please include @ symbol");
        email.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (email.value.indexOf(".")== -1 ) {
        alert("Please include . symbol");
        email.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (cardnumber.value.length!=16 || isNaN(cardnumber.value)){
        alert("Please enter yout 16 digit credit card number");
        cardnumber.focus();
        return false;
    }   
    if (ccv.value.length!=3 || isNaN(cardnumber.value)){
        alert("Please enter yout 3 digit ccv");
        ccv.focus();
        return false;






    }
    alert("Thank you for your submission");
    return true;
}

function Help() {
var Window1 = window.open("", "", "width=350, height=100");
Window1.document.write("<p>Required fields cannot be left blank<br>The email address must contain an @ and a dot<br>The credit card month and year must be valid<br>The postcode must contain four numbers<br>Enter the ccv<p>")
return;
}
```

Comment: Where is your attempt to answer the question you have posed? I can't see the button, switch statement or anything you are describing.

Comment: You do realize I hope, that an `option` element needs both opening **and** closing tags. I.e `<option value='valueGoesHere'>labelGoesHere</option>`